# Expand recurring events for the next 2 years

Tags: calendar, caml, recurring-events

How can I get an expanded list of recurring events for the next 2 years?

I am currently using this CAML expression:

```
<DateRangesOverlap>
    <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
    <Value Type="DateTime"><Year /></Value>
</DateRangesOverlap>
```

Unfortunately, I only get the instances for the next 12 months.

Comment: Out of curiosity did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @RJCuthbertson no, we just accepted it as a technical limitation.

Answer (score 1):

For best results of getting recurring events for the next 2 years, I recommend you do 24 x 1 month queries starting with this month.  You have to take mind duplicates between months, because on the one month queries, SharePoint will return events that recur near the month boundaries.  See my answer to another question here:

[CAML query recurrent events problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27181/caml-query-recurrent-events-problem)

The reason we do 1 month queries is we found that doing full year queries, SharePoint will throttle your results, so you won't get full results.