# How Does Calender List DateRangesOverlap <Today/>,<Month/>,<Year/> and <Week/> exactly work?

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar, spquery, recurring-events

I have a SharePoint calendar list which has some recurring events i wanted a report of about last two years. Following is the code that i have written

```
SPQuery qryBookings = new SPQuery();
                            qryBookings.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                                                      "<FieldRef Name='LinkedBID'/>" +
                                                   "<FieldRef Name='Hosted_x0020_By'/>" +
                                                   "<FieldRef Name='Author'/>" +
                                                   "<FieldRef Name='Editor'/>" +
                                               "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                                               "<FieldRef Name='EventDate'/>" +
                                                "<FieldRef Name='Duration'/>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Room'/>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Place'/>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Linked_x0020_Id'/>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='UID'/>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Is_x0020_Linked'/>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence'/>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Internal_x0020_Meeting'/>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                             "<FieldRef Name='MasterSeriesItemID'/>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='EventType'/>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Virtual_x0020_Room'/>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Changeit'/>";
                            qryBookings.Query = "<Where>" +
                                            "<DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +//<And>
                                            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                                            "<Value Type='DateTime'><Year/></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where><GroupBy Collapse ='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='EventDate'></FieldRef></GroupBy>";//<Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>4</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Linked_x0020_Id' /><Value Type='Text'>96312753-ca76-466f-87d4-c0f2387c2390</Value></Eq></And>

                            qryBookings.ExpandRecurrence = true;
                            qryBookings.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now;


                            SPListItemCollection bk_collec = lstBookings.GetItems(qryBookings);
```

According to most of the blogs `<Year/>` returns all the events in the year in which the `qryBookings.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now;` falls.

Now today is 17th Sept 2014 and on testing i found that the results returned are from 17th Sept 2013 to 17th June 2015 which is different from what most of the blogs say. i.e. [this](http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2013/04/30/daterangesoverlap/)

Can anyone explain me what exactly happens and also let me know if there is a way where i can request for events which are in the span of more than a year.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My experience has found that doing calendar queries with recurrence expansion for a year are not dependable as SharePoint might throttle the results.  I do not have specifics on why this happens.

I found the most dependable results by doing 1 month queries.  So if you need to do 1 year - break it down into 12 months and for 2 years - 24 months.

See my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27181/caml-query-recurrent-events-problem) for more details and edge events you will want to take care of if you decide to do 1 month queries.

This was for SharePoint 2007 and 2010.  I have not tested the dependability of year long queries against SharePoint 2013 [yet].